# EXC_BAD_ACCESS and/or EXC_BREAKPOINT in WKWebView - possible changes to fix that swift

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, exc-bad-access

I implemented in my UIViewController a WKWebViewDelegate, because the website behind this WKWebView needs permission to camera and have to open inside app, because of Apple Design Guidelines.

In my test environment everything is working. I use crashyltics to analyse my apps in live environment. 10-15% of my users (100% = 130 daily users) will get the following problem.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x182691968 CFRunLoopAddTimer + 88
1  JavaScriptCore                 0x186f6cf98 WTF::RunLoop::TimerBase::start(double, bool) + 188
2  **WebKit**                         0x18bb8362c IPC::ConnectionTerminationWatchdog::ConnectionTerminationWatchdog(WTF::OSObjectPtr<NSObject<OS_xpc_object>*>&, double) + 164
3  **WebKit**                         0x18bb826d0 IPC::ConnectionTerminationWatchdog::createConnectionTerminationWatchdog(WTF::OSObjectPtr<NSObject<OS_xpc_object>*>&, double) + 48
4  WebKit                         0x18bb7c488 WebKit::ChildProcessProxy::shutDownProcess() + 76
5  WebKit                         0x18bd35cd0 WebKit::WebProcessProxy::shutDown() + 36
6  WebKit                         0x18bd36244 WebKit::WebProcessProxy::removeWebPage(unsigned long long) + 432
7  WebKit                         0x18bcd0934 WebKit::WebPageProxy::close() + 536
8  WebKit                         0x18bdc3200 -[WKWebView dealloc] + 112
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1811f5fe0 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 704
10 UIKit                          0x188658668 -[UIView dealloc] + 1644
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1811f5fe0 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 704
12 UIKit                          0x188658668 -[UIView dealloc] + 1644
....
```

Another error is

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libdispatch.dylib              0x190daaf20 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 596
1  WebKit                         0x19b37701c __64-[WKProcessAssertionBackgroundTaskManager _updateBackgroundTask]_block_invoke + 240
2  WebKit                         0x19b37701c __64-[WKProcessAssertionBackgroundTaskManager _updateBackgroundTask]_block_invoke + 240
```

So I read a lot about EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I understand that a reference point to an object that is nil.

**HOW MY WKWebView Looks Like**

This is my structure in my storyboard:

[image]

I need to use a ContainerView, because my code just work with the line `self.view = self.webView` Tried to took just a view but then the WKWebView doesn't initialize.

```
  //WKWebView in Container
  var webView: WKWebView!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView = WKWebView()

    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.view = self.webView

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if self.url.characters.count > 0 {
            if let url = NSURL(string: self.url) {
                self.webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
                self.webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Last but not least I detect that when I call the WKWebView (Or the ViewController with the ContainerView that include the WKWebView) with

`viewController.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

and dismiss with

`super.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag, completion: completion)`

the memory won't deallocate. So I could (when I call the WKWebView over 100 times) get a memory leak. In the live environment this scenario is really improbable.

However.. the problem is that I can't reproduce this error that my users get. So the question to you before I will send a next version to App Store: Do you see a no go in my code? Something that could threw this errors?

I changed parts of my code to that:

1. uncomment dispatch_async or use `//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] () -> Void in`
2. set webView to optional `var webView:WKWebView?`

Comment: any luck with a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It was very confusing. My procedure was: User click on Button to WKWebview. I ask for the camera permission. User gave or gave not. User go back. The App shutdown.

When I don't ask for the camera permission then there weren't no interrupts anymore. More I can't find out.